# Displaying selected info from Class Constructor into a table - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to relate selected options in a dropdown within a form in html to objects created via a class constructor in JS. I'm struggling to link the two and am only managing to display some names, and all within one row in a html table. 
Ideally, I'd like to relate the items within my display() function and display values from my objects, rather than using values directly from the form.

This is my full code:

```js
/* See/add options, remove options, 
see overview of options and price
 */
// VARIABLES 
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
let choice = document.getElementById("choice");
let optionChosen = document.getElementById("option");
let optionPrice = document.getElementById("optionPrice");

// OPTIONS CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
class CarOptions {
    constructor(optionName, price) {
        this.optionName = optionName;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// create 6 options
let option = new CarOptions("", 0);
let vac = new CarOptions("vac", 150);
let trunk = new CarOptions("trunk", 2000);
let seat = new CarOptions("seat", 550);
let night = new CarOptions("night", 360);
let wifi = new CarOptions("wifi", 1200);
let park = new CarOptions("park", 600);
// Array of all objects
let allOptions = [option, vac, trunk, seat, night, wifi, park];
// Array of all object names
let allOptionsName = [option.optionName, vac.optionName, trunk.optionName, seat.optionName, night.optionName, wifi.optionName, park.optionName];

// EVENTS
// On submit event
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#choice option:checked');
    // Displaying options names in the table
    // CURRENTLY ALL DISPLAYS IN ONE ROW 
    allOptionsName.forEach(function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < allOptionsName.length; i++) {
            const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
            optionChosen.innerHTML = values;
            console.log(values);
            console.log("this value: " + values);
            display();
        }
    });
})

function display(element) {
    if (values.value != "") {
        optionChosen.innerHTML = element.optionName;
        optionPrice.innerHTML = element.price;
    }
    return;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}
#form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 250px;
    align-items: center;
}
#choice {
    height: 120px;
}
.results {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px dotted green;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Car Selection</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Car Choice</h1>
    <h2>Ready to buy your dream car?</h2>
    <div class="select">
        <!-- Selection of food or drink -->
        <form class="flexColumn" id="form">
            <select name="choice" id="choice" multiple="true">
                <option value="" name="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option id="vac" value="vac" name="vac">Built-in Vacuum (€150)</option>
                <option value="trunk" name="trunk">Automatic Opening Trunk (€2000)</option>
                <option value="seat" name="seat">Massaging Seats (€550)</option>
                <option value="night" name="night">Nightvision Dashboard System (€360)</option>
                <option value="wifi" name="wifi">WiFi/Entertainment/Navigation (€1200)</option>
                <option value="park" name="park">Self-Parking System (€600)</option>
            </select>
            <button id="submit" class="submit" submit>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
        <p>Your current selected options:</p>
        <div id="selection" class="selection">
            <table class="results" style="width:200px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Option</th>
                    <th>Price (€)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="emptyRow">
                    <td id="option"></td>
                    <td id="optionPrice"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TOTAL:</td>
                    <td id="totalPrice"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are expecting an argument in `function display(element)` but when you are calling it in 'click' event listener you haven't provided any argument. Also you are trying to access 'values' in `display` function which is not defined in `display` but in the `click` function. What are you trying to pass to the `display` function? Fix these issues first and edit your code and post correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
/* See/add options, remove options, 
see overview of options and price
 */
// VARIABLES 
let button = document.querySelector("#submit");
let choice = document.querySelector("#choice");

// OPTIONS CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
class CarOptions {
  constructor(optionName, price) {
    this.optionName = optionName;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
// create 6 options
let option = new CarOptions("", 0);
let vac = new CarOptions("vac", 150);
let trunk = new CarOptions("trunk", 2000);
let seat = new CarOptions("seat", 550);
let night = new CarOptions("night", 360);
let wifi = new CarOptions("wifi", 1200);
let park = new CarOptions("park", 600);
// Array of all objects
let allOptions = [option, vac, trunk, seat, night, wifi, park];
// Array of all object names
let allOptionsName = [option.optionName, vac.optionName, trunk.optionName, seat.optionName, night.optionName, wifi.optionName, park.optionName];

// EVENTS
// On submit event
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#choice option:checked');
  const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
  const res = allOptions.filter(a => values.includes(a.optionName))
  const total = res.reduce((acc, v) => acc += v.price, 0 )
  display(res, total);
})
function createTr() {
  let tbodyRef = document.querySelectorAll("#cars");
  let newRow = tbodyRef[0].insertRow();
  return newRow
}
function createTd(el, newTr) {
  let newel = document.createElement('td');
  let elementid = document.querySelectorAll("td").length
  newel.setAttribute('id',elementid);
  newel.innerHTML = el
  newTr.appendChild(newel);
}
function display(element, total) {
  element.forEach(e => {
    const newTr = createTr()
    createTd(e.optionName, newTr)
    createTd(e.price, newTr)
  })
  const tot = document.querySelector("#totalPrice")
  tot.innerHTML = total
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}
#form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 250px;
    align-items: center;
}
#choice {
    height: 120px;
}
.results {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px dotted green;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Car Selection</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Car Choice</h1>
    <h2>Ready to buy your dream car?</h2>
    <div class="select">
        <!-- Selection of food or drink -->
        <form class="flexColumn" id="form">
            <select name="choice" id="choice" multiple="true">
                <option value="" name="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option id="vac" value="vac" name="vac">Built-in Vacuum (€150)</option>
                <option value="trunk" name="trunk">Automatic Opening Trunk (€2000)</option>
                <option value="seat" name="seat">Massaging Seats (€550)</option>
                <option value="night" name="night">Nightvision Dashboard System (€360)</option>
                <option value="wifi" name="wifi">WiFi/Entertainment/Navigation (€1200)</option>
                <option value="park" name="park">Self-Parking System (€600)</option>
            </select>
            <button id="submit" class="submit" submit>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
        <p>Your current selected options:</p>
        <div id="selection" class="selection">
            <table class="results" style="width:200px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Option</th>
                    <th>Price (€)</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="cars">
                <tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <td>TOTAL:</td>
                    <td id="totalPrice"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have done, perfect. I just need to figure out how to make it reactive as I select or deselect (it currenty just adds items on) and to add a delete button :-)

Comment: You can make another list populated with selected items, and attach event on that new list, that on click remove clicked item

Comment: Ok, I'll try. For now, I've managed the reset form button:

Comment: resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    inputForm.reset();
})

Answer (score 0):

The options are displaying in one row because you only have selected one table row and inserted all your values in it. You will have to create table row for each of your value. To display values in rows, try this: -

```js
/* See/add options, remove options, 
see overview of options and price
 */
// VARIABLES 
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
let choice = document.getElementById("choice");
let row = document.getElementById('emptyRow');
let totalPriceElement = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

// OPTIONS CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
class CarOptions {
    constructor(optionName, price) {
        this.optionName = optionName;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// create 6 options
let option = new CarOptions("", 0);
let vac = new CarOptions("vac", 150);
let trunk = new CarOptions("trunk", 2000);
let seat = new CarOptions("seat", 550);
let night = new CarOptions("night", 360);
let wifi = new CarOptions("wifi", 1200);
let park = new CarOptions("park", 600);
// Array of all objects
let allOptions = [option, vac, trunk, seat, night, wifi, park];
// Array of all object names
let allOptionsName = [option.optionName, vac.optionName, trunk.optionName, seat.optionName, night.optionName, wifi.optionName, park.optionName];

// EVENTS
// On submit event
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#choice option:checked');
    // Displaying options names in the table
    // CURRENTLY ALL DISPLAYS IN ONE ROW 

   
        for(let i = 0; i < selected.length;i++){
            
            const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
            const element = allOptions.filter(option => {
                return option.optionName == values[i];
                
            });
          
            var tableRow = document.createElement('TR');
            var tableCellName = document.createElement('TD');
            var tableCellPrice = document.createElement('TD');
            tableCellName.setAttribute('class','option');
            tableCellName.innerText = values[i];
            tableCellPrice.setAttribute('class','price');
            tableCellPrice.innerText = element[0].price;
            tableRow.appendChild(tableCellName);
            tableRow.appendChild(tableCellPrice);
            row.appendChild(tableRow);
          

         
            if(i == selected.length - 1){
                display(values);
            }
       }
        
   
})

function display(values) {
    const elements = allOptions.filter(option => {
       
        for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            if(option.optionName == values[i]){
                return option; 
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    })
    let totalPrice = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<elements.length;i++){
        totalPrice += elements[i].price;
    }
    totalPriceElement.innerText = totalPrice;
    return;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}
#form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 250px;
    align-items: center;
}
#choice {
    height: 120px;
}
.results {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px dotted green;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Car Selection</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Car Choice</h1>
    <h2>Ready to buy your dream car?</h2>
    <div class="select">
        <!-- Selection of food or drink -->
        <form class="flexColumn" id="form">
            <select name="choice" id="choice" multiple="true">
                <option value="" name="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option id="vac" value="vac" name="vac">Built-in Vacuum (€150)</option>
                <option value="trunk" name="trunk">Automatic Opening Trunk (€2000)</option>
                <option value="seat" name="seat">Massaging Seats (€550)</option>
                <option value="night" name="night">Nightvision Dashboard System (€360)</option>
                <option value="wifi" name="wifi">WiFi/Entertainment/Navigation (€1200)</option>
                <option value="park" name="park">Self-Parking System (€600)</option>
            </select>
            <button id="submit" class="submit" submit>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
        <p>Your current selected options:</p>
        <div id="selection" class="selection">
            <table class="results" style="width:200px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Option</th>
                    <th>Price (€)</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="emptyRow">
                    
                </tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>TOTAL:</td>
                    <td id="totalPrice"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This code will make your options display in multiple rows along with the price and the total price.